# Appstore Flutter App Rejection Because of In app purchuase

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store

My app is rejected because of in app purchase. I am using [in_app_purchase 0.3.0+2](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/versions). How can I put "Restore" button for ios?

> We found that your app offers in-app purchases that can be restored but does not include a "Restore Purchases" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased in-app purchases, as specified in the "Restoring Purchase Products" section of the In-App Purchase Programming Guide:
>
> Users restore transactions to maintain access to content they've already purchased. For example, when they upgrade to a new phone, they don't lose all of the items they purchased on the old phone. Include some mechanism in your app to let the user restore their purchases, such as a Restore Purchases button.
>
> Next Steps
>       To restore previously purchased in-app purchase products, it would be appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore
>   process when the "Restore" button is tapped by the user. Note that
>   automatically restoring purchases on launch will not resolve this
>   issue.

Comment: You just need to add a "Restore Purchase" button in the iOS part. So when user click that button, the previously purchased items will be unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use login/signup method for save all purchased account in your own server and the user can login with another device and login and then can restore purchased service. or you can just use apple id [queryPastPurchases] to get past purchases.